# JS for loop in for loop, problem with scope I guess

Tags: javascript, for-loop, scope, nested-loops

The input is an array ints [11, 2, 7, 8, 4, 6] and and integer s 10. The function is to output an array with a pair of two numbers from ints which first form a sum of 10. So here the output should be [2, 8], because 2 + 8 = 10. Why does it output empty array? The arrResults was updated in the nested for loop, so why doesn't it show up like that after the final return statement?

```js
function sumPairs(ints, s) {
  let arrResults = [];
  let sumOfTwo;
  for (i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < ints.length; j++) {
      sumOfTwo = ints[i] + ints[j];
      if (sumOfTwo === s) {
        arrResults.push(ints[i]);
        arrResults.push(ints[j]);
        break;
      }
    }
    if (arrResults !== []) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return arrResults;
}

console.log(sumPairs([11, 2, 7, 8, 4, 6], 10));
```

Comment: in the for loop I think you should be doing `let i=0` and `let j = 0`

Comment: I just tried but it makes no difference.

Comment: your second loop is wrong, you should not be starting from zero.

Comment: you can just return [ints[i],ints[j]] once you find sumoftwo === s instead of making the array of results

Comment: `arrResults !== []` is not how one looks to see if an array has elements, hence your problem

Answer (score 1):

Beside the wrong comparing of an array with another array (without having the same object reference)

```
a = []
b = []

a === b // false

// other example

a = []
b = a

a === b // true
```

for checking the length,

```
a = []
a.length // 0
```

and by using a nearly quadratic time complexity of n², even with looping

```
i = 0; i < array.length - 1
j = i + 1; j < array.length
```

which is more then the half of n², but strill quadratic,

you could take a **single loop** with an object fo already seen values.

This approach finds the first pair of the array for a certain sum.

```js
function sumPairs(ints, s) {
    const needed = {};

    for (const value of ints) {
        if (needed[value]) return [s - value, value];
        needed[s - value] = true;
    }
}

console.log(sumPairs([11, 2, 7, 8, 4, 6], 10));
```

Comment: Seriously clever answer.. in O(n). Nice.

Comment: Nina Scholz thank you for this amazing solution, it took me a while to grasp it, now as I understand how it works I'm amazed it was that simple:-) Magic!

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails because you are checking to see if the array is empty. The problem is that check is never going to be false, so it exits on the first iteration.

```js
console.log([]===[]);
console.log([]!==[]);
```

So code with changes to improve performance and to exit out

```js
function sumPairs(ints, s) {
  let arrResults = [];
  let sumOfTwo;
  for (let i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < ints.length; j++) {
      sumOfTwo = ints[i] + ints[j];
      if (sumOfTwo === s) {
        arrResults.push(ints[i]);
        arrResults.push(ints[j]);
        break;
      }
    }
    if (arrResults.length) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return arrResults;
}

console.log(sumPairs([11, 2, 7, 8, 4, 6], 10));
```

There is no need to break out twice, just return the array

```js
function sumPairs(ints, s) {
  let arrResults = [];
  let sumOfTwo;
  for (let i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < ints.length; j++) {
      sumOfTwo = ints[i] + ints[j];
      if (sumOfTwo === s) {
        return [ints[i], ints[j]];
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}

console.log(sumPairs([11, 2, 7, 8, 4, 6], 10));
```