# Summing pairs in loop does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, duplicates

Below is the task description and my two attempts to write a function (both output wrong results, for example check my second function with these arguments:

```
sumPairs([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5], 10); 
*outputs [5, 5], should be [3, 7]*
sumPairs([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 6, 13, 9], 10);
*outputs [1, 9], should be [2, 8]*
```

Please  point out what's wrong in my way of tackling this.
Below I explain what I tried to do.

..................................

> TASK DESCRIPTION:
>
> Sum of Pairs.
>
> Given a list of integers and a single sum value, return the first two
> values (parse from the left please) in order of appearance that add up
> to form the sum.
>
> sum_pairs([11, 3, 7, 5], 10).
>
> Result: 3 + 7 = 10
>
> sum_pairs([4, 3, 2, 3, 4], 6).
>
> Result: 4 + 2 = 6, because earliest indices: 0, 2, because the entire
> pair is earlier.
>
> sum_pairs([0, 0, -2, 3], 2).
>
> Result: undefined.
>
> sum_pairs([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5], 10).
>
> Result: 3 + 7 = 10, indices: 3, 4, because the entire pair is earlier,
> and therefore is the correct answer.
>
> Negative numbers and duplicate numbers can and will appear.
>
> NOTE: There will also be lists tested of lengths upwards of 10,000,000
> elements. Be sure your code doesn't time out.
> ........................................

My plan was to: loop over each element of ints array, addiding each element to other elements of ints array (except addiding the same element to itself), until it finds 1 or 2 pairs of elements which add up to the s sum:*

```js
function sumPairs(ints, s) {
  let arrResults = [];
  let sumOfTwo;
  for (i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < ints.length; j++) {
      if (j !== i) {
        sumOfTwo = ints[i] + ints[j];
        if (sumOfTwo === s) {
          return [ints[i], ints[j]];
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return undefined;
}

console.log(
sumPairs([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5], 10),
// *outputs [5, 5], should be [3, 7]*
sumPairs([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 6, 13, 9], 10)
// *outputs [1, 9], should be [2, 8]*

)
```

I used break statements to stop the loops as soon as they find the first 1 or 2 pairs. After finding 2 pairs of elements, choose which pair is "earlier" (has earlier indexes) in the ints array. Of course the problem with indexOf duplicates occurs again. So I tried to create a separate counter in every loop. Then push the results into a separate arrResults and choose the best pair:

```js
function sumPairs(ints, s) {
  let arrResults = [];
  let sumOfTwo;
  let iIndexCount = 0;
  let jIndexCount = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < ints.length; j++) {
      if (j !== i) {
        sumOfTwo = ints[i] + ints[j];
        if (sumOfTwo === s) {
          arrResults.push(ints[i], ints[j], jIndexCount - iIndexCount);
        }
      }
      jIndexCount++;
      if (arrResults.length === 9) {
        break;
      }
    }
    iIndexCount++;
    if (arrResults.length === 9) {
      break;
    }
  }

  if (arrResults.length === 9) {
    if (arrResults[2] <= arrResults[8]) {
      return [arrResults[0], arrResults[1]];
    } else {
      return [arrResults[6], arrResults[7]];
    }
  } else if (arrResults.length === 6) {
    return [arrResults[0], arrResults[1]];
  } else {
    return undefined;
  }
}

console.log(
sumPairs([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5], 10), 
// *outputs [5, 5], should be [3, 7]*
sumPairs([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 6, 13, 9], 10)
// *outputs [1, 9], should be [2, 8]*
)
```

Comment: I edited your question into a set of [mcve] and fixed your title. Please have a look. It is now readable and reproducible

Comment: what about the question from [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68913272/js-for-loop-in-for-loop-problem-with-scope-i-guess/68913590#68913590)?

Answer (score 0):

This approach uses a `Set()` to store numbers resulting in only one loop being needed.

Inspired by NinaScholz's answer to your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68913272/js-for-loop-in-for-loop-problem-with-scope-i-guess/68913590#68913590):

```js
    
function sumPairs(ints, s) {
    const set = new Set();
    for(let n of ints) {
        if (set.has(s - n)) {
          return ([s - n, n]);
        } else {
          set.add(n);
        }
    }
}


console.log(sumPairs([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5], 10))
console.log(sumPairs([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 6, 13, 9], 10))
console.log(sumPairs([11, 3, 7, 5], 10))
console.log(sumPairs([4, 3, 2, 3, 4], 6))
console.log(sumPairs([11, 1, 7, 5], 10));
```

Comment: Thank you, looks like it works for most inputs, however with this input: sumPairs([11, 1, 7, 5], 10);  it shows "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'pair' of 'ints.reduce(...)' as it is null."

Comment: Aha, thank you for checking.. I'll see what I can do with that. I believe I've fixed it now..

Comment: Brilliant solution. Trying to explain:

ints.reduce((acc,n,i - reducer function with 3 parameters: accumulated sum, current number, current index).

Inner for loop, checking: if the current n number plus the current j value equal s AND... and from here I don't get it... AND if the accumulated sum previously returned OR current j are smaller than acc.loc then we assign to acc an object with two keys: 
loc: current j number 
pair: array with current n number and current j.
At the end we return acc object.
Then null)?.pair; I don't get that either: we access pair property of acc object?

Comment: It's kind of tricky to understand alright. I've switched it out for what I think is a simpler and better one. But to explain a little, we basically run through the ints array using reduce().. then within that loop we look at every number further on than our current one. If both numbers sum to s _and_ have a lower loc (ie they're the first pair to fulfill the criteria), we replace acc with them. The ?. operator just says if acc is null (e.g. we haven't found a match) don't throw an error, just return _undefined_.

Comment: Thank you, this solution is so short and brilliant. To figure it out I had to learn what new Set() is, and now I get it. Here's another solution someone proposed, also surprisingly short: 
`var sum_pairs=function(ints, s){
  var seen = {}
  for (var i = 0; i < ints.length; ++i) {
    if (seen[s - ints[i]]) return [s - ints[i], ints[i]];
    seen[ints[i]] = true
  }
}`

Comment: Ah yes, that's very similar alright. Both are O(n) using big O notation as opposed to O(n²) for some other implementations. This won't make much difference for a list of 10 numbers, but with 1000 or 1000000 items it would make a _big_ difference! It's a fun problem to work on in any case!

Answer (score 0):

Following the comments to the previous (wrong) answer, here you can see an amended (and commented) version:

```js
function sumPairs(arr, sum) {
  const pairs = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let first = arr[i];
    if (first < sum) { // no point in checking anything, if the number itself is already equal to or bigger than the expected sum
      /*
       * As a + b === b + a, it is pointless to compare the sum of an item
       * with any preceding item because that would have been already checked
       * therefore each number will be compared only with the following ones,
       * in order to avoid unnecessary iterations
       */
      const rest = arr.slice(i + 1);
      for (let j = 0; j < rest.length; j++) {
        const second = rest[j];
        if (second < sum && first + second === sum) pairs.push({
          pair: [first, second],
          lastIndex: j // storing the last index will make easier to sort the pairs later
        });
      }
    }
  }

  return pairs.length === 0
    // no pair found
    ?
    undefined :
    pairs.length === 1
    // only one pair found
    ?
    pairs[0].pair
    // more then one pair found: order pairs by the index  (lowest to highest index)
    // of the second number and pick the first one
    :
    pairs.sort((a, b) => a.lastIndex - b.lastIndex)[0].pair
}

// test
console.log('#testing sumPairs([11, 3, 7, 5], 10):');
console.log(sumPairs([11, 3, 7, 5], 10));
console.log('#testing sumPairs([4, 3, 2, 3, 4], 6):');
console.log(sumPairs([4, 3, 2, 3, 4], 6));
console.log('#testing sumPairs([0, 0, -2, 3], 2):');
console.log(sumPairs([0, 0, -2, 3], 2));
console.log('#testing sumPairs([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5], 10):');
console.log(sumPairs([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5], 10));
```

Comment: I just checked the first of your functions and it gives wrong results as well:
Your sum_pairs([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 6, 13, 9], 10)  outputs [1, 9], should be [2, 8] because this pair is closer to each other (look at the task description);
Your sumpairs([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5], 10)  outputs [5, 5], should be [3, 7] because this pair is closer to each other.

Comment: Besides, in your first function: if on every iteration you slice the array, on next iterations you will lose the beginning portion of the array (the first elements to compare with). In other words, every iteration narrows down the "rest" of j's to compare with previous i's. Right?

Comment: Your second function sum_pairs2 gives wrong result as well. 
([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 6, 13, 9], 10) outputs [1, 9], should be [2, 8]
([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5], 10) outputs [5, 5], should be [3, 7].
Thank you for help, but this task is more complicated than that. It's to output the sum pair which has lowest indexes and at the same moment the elements of the pair are closest to each other.

Comment: @NataliaGrzywacz, you are right; I misinterpreted the meaning of "earlier/earliest" in the requirements; thanks for pointing that out. I am going to delete the answer in a few minutes, just to give you the time for reading this answer. For what concerns the `slice()`, that was an intended behavior as it would have saved some unnecessary iterations (if I already checked the sum of the first element with the second one, there is no point in checking the sum of the second element with the first one or with itself in the following iteration).

Comment: This new version should meet the requirements

Answer (score 0):

This was fun - a bit over engineered but gives indicii and distances

Sort on distance (AND idx1 if needed)

```js
function sumPair(list, s) {
  var pairs = []
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < list.length; j++) {
      const sum = list[i] + list[j]
      if (sum === s) pairs.push({
        idx1: i,
        first: list[i],
        idx2: j,
        second: list[j],
        distance: j - i
      });
    }
  }
  if (pairs.length) return pairs.sort((a,b) => a.distance - b.distance)[0]
  return undefined;
};

let { first, second } = sumPair([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 6, 13, 9], 10)
console.log(first,second)

// similar for the rest
console.log(sumPair([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5], 10));
console.log(sumPair([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 6, 13, 9], 10))
console.log(sumPair([3, 1, 4, 1, 2, 6, 5], 8))
console.log(sumPair([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 6, 13, 9], 21))
```